# Change Read Only attribute from sharepoint 2010 List Column

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-list

I have created a list using "**Custom List in Data Sheet View**". After that I created around 10 columns in that list. Problem is only for one column, it is showing as read only, rest all are working fine!! Hence I cannot insert a row in the list(Data sheet view).

**How can I remove that read only attribute from the column?**

One more related question is, how to make the list editable to only one group and read only to other groups?

Thank you, for your valuable inputs!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer this [question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/22516/change-read-only-attribute-from-sharepoint-2010-list-column)... Once I delete and re created the column, the read only option has gone. Also given separate permission for the user **after stopping the security inheritance from parent option in the list's permission.**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with two columns in a list. I discovered the "Type of Text to Allow" for both columns were set to "Enhanced Rich Text". Changing the "Type of Text to Allow" for the column to only "Rich Text" solved the problem for both columns.